# Android - notifyDataSetChanged causes "changed the adapter's contents without calling notifyDataSetChanged"

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

i have a weird issue: i have a View Pager with a FragmentPagerAdapter.

After changing some things in my dataset i called notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter and i got following crash Log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 3, found: 2 Pager id: com.package:id/pager Pager class: class com.package.MyPager Problematic adapter: class com.package.MyAdapter
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:967)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:555)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:913)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2824)
at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
```

i cant explain why, and what code would be helpful here...

it does not happen always, only sometimes

Comment: Could you show us the code in your PagerAdapter? The error is pretty clear.

Comment: do any adapter changes in the UI thread, not in a background thread